# Proving that a function is constant from functional equation

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

$a,b \in (0,1)$ and $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous functions s.t. $ \int_0^x f(x)dx=\int_0^{ax}f(x)dx+ \int_0^{bx}f(x)dx$ . Knowing that $a+b=1$, we have to prove that $f$ is constant.

Using the derivative,we get:
$f(x)=af(ax)+bf(bx)$

I managed to do it for the case $a=b=1/2$, but I don't know how to make it with $a,b$ arbitrary and $a,b \in (0,1)$ $a+b=1$

Comment: Note the OP asked the same question again about $2$ hours later at [$ \int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^{ax}f(t)dt+ \int_0^{bx}f(t)dt$ implies $f$ constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146525/int-0x-ftdt-int-0axftdt-int-0bxftdt-implies-f-constant).

Answer (score 2):

I think it should read:

$\int_0^1 f(t)dt=\int_0^{ax}f(t)dt+ \int_0^{bx}f(t)dt.$

Then $ f(x)=af(ax)+bf(bx)$ is not correct. Using derivatives, you get $0=af(ax)+bf(bx)$, since

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 f(t)dt=0.$

Comment: Sorry. I corrected.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^1 f(t)dt = lim_{a->0}\int_0^{ax}f(t)dt + 
lim_{a->0}\int_0^{bx}f(t)dt = \int_0^{x}f(t)dt$.

Taking derivatives of both sides, 0 = f(x).

Comment: Sorry. I corrected.